# Open Java Console With C# Issue

Tags: c#, java, process

I'm trying to open a Java application that runs a console from C#

My code to do this:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

          Process process = new Process();
          process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\";
          process.StartInfo.FileName = "monkeyrunner.bat";
          process.Start();
    }
```

If I directly run the monkeyrunner.bat file directly from the folder it is in it works no problem. But if i try and open it using the above I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Brad\AppData
\Local\Temp\jline_.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
        at jline.WindowsTerminal.loadLibrary(WindowsTerminal.java:315)
        at jline.WindowsTerminal.initializeTerminal(WindowsTerminal.java:240)
        at jline.Terminal.setupTerminal(Terminal.java:75)
        at org.python.util.JLineConsole.(JLineConsole.java:69)
        at org.python.util.JLineConsole.(JLineConsole.java:53)
        at org.python.util.JLineConsole.(JLineConsole.java:49)
        at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.console(ScriptRunner.java:192)
        at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.
java:73)
        at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter
.java:189)
```

Anyone have any ideas why opening the process from C# would cause an issue?

I get the same issue if i try and run the Java file the Bat file is opening.

EDIT:

I think I know what the issue is now:

if I open a CMD from windows it runs as a 64bit console.. But as my application is built in 32bit (using express) its loading a 32bit console.. But i can't see a way I can open the 64bit console from a 32bit application

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit operating system? Then you can't run applications that depend on 64-bit DLLs.

Comment: IT's a 64 bit OS.. Also if it wasn't why would it only not work when opening it via C#?

Comment: Maybe the C# Runtime you are using to start the process is 32 bit? Or you compiled for 32 bit only?

Comment: I think I know what the issue is now:

if I open a CMD from windows it runs as a 64bit console.. But as my application is built in 32bit (using express) its loading a 32bit console.. But i can't see a way I can open the 64bit console from a 32bit application

Comment: Have you tried making "Program Files" (rather than "Program Files (x86)") the working directory?

Comment: You could try running the 64 bit cmd.exe `C:\Windows
\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` as your process and pass the batch file as an arguement to it.

Comment: Actually, look here http://superuser.com/questions/362206/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-windows-cmd-file-batch-file-as-32-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around was to compile application as x86. This prevented the wrong cmd.exe from being loaded.